# How to install RStudio on Raspberry Pi(RaspbianOS)

Tags: r, ubuntu, raspberry-pi, rstudio, raspbian

How to install RStudio on RaspbianOS?!! I have tried Ubuntu MATE 64 and 32 bit but neither work! Even `wget` or using the installer (by installer I mean `Pi-gpk-dbus-service`) or nothing works! It says  something like Failed to install because some package is missing. But I do have have R-Base and it works on neither Ubuntu or RaspbianOS! So I can infer the issue is with my Raspberry Pi. But how do I solve this issue? How to actually install RStudio on a Raspberry Pi(RaspbianOS)? Please let me know if it is even possible to install RStudio on a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: A Raspberry Pi does not run an Intel (or compatible) cpu, _i.e._ it really is a different "architecture" from your standard PC or laptop running Windows/Linux/macOS.  As such, you cannot just drop a binary there and expect it to work.

Comment: See info here: https://community.rstudio.com/t/rstudio-desktop-on-raspberry-pi/21688

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your question is not specific, I'm assuming you're after the Desktop version since there seems to be a good guide for the server version (e.g. https://community.rstudio.com/t/setting-up-your-own-shiny-server-rstudio-server-on-a-raspberry-pi-3b/18982) but I could not find a definitive answer for the desktop version.

I've spent a fair amount of time trying to install RStudio on my Raspberry Pi 4 using all the different scripts offered here:

- https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio
- https://github.com/ArturKlauser/raspberrypi-rstudio

  - And all the forks here:
  - https://github.com/ArturKlauser/raspberrypi-rstudio/network/members

It eventually failed because one or more of the dependencies either did not compile for 32-bit or Arm.

Also tried the Docker way suggested here: https://community.rstudio.com/t/rstudio-desktop-on-raspberry-pi/21688, same Arm issue.

The one thing that did work was the cloud version of RStudio which I'm nowadays using: https://www.rstudio.com/products/cloud/. It's not the same as having RStudio in your own device, but it's powerful enough to get things done if I don't have another machine available. Below is a snapshot of a ODE solver on RStudio Cloud.

[image: RStudio Desktop on Cloud]

The free version of RStudio Cloud only has one CPU available, limited RAM and limited runtime per month. For some applications, this is enough so I'm sharing this solution here for those who like me did not know of this alternative solution.